# Qt MainWindow | ui->setupUi(this) error

Tags: qt, user-interface, qmainwindow

I keep getting an error when using: ui->setupUi(this) error
If anyone knows what the error might be, I would be very grateful.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this); // This is where the error occurs 
   scanningNow = false;
   setBackground = false;
   displayRef = false;
   fileName = "NIR Spectra";
   initCalib();
   initSettings();

   initUI();
   USB_Init();

   emit checkUSB();

   #ifdef USB_POLL_ENABLED
      usbPollTimer = new QTimer(this);
      usbPollTimer -> setInterval(5000);
      connect(usbPollTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerTimeout()));
      usbPollTimer -> start();
   #endif

}
```

The error is: ***'cannot initialize object parameter of type 'Ui_MainWindow' with an expression of type 'Ui::MainWindow'***

Comment: Did you change manually the ui_mainwindow.h file that is automatically made by by Moc?

Comment: @GabriellaGiordano That file is made by `uic`, not moc.

Comment: @Kuba Ober correct. My bad :) but still the question remains...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same issue. No qmake or compile errors when I actually build the project but it's very annoying nonetheless.